# "Help" Link in Area51's discussion area points to a 404

Tags: bug, area-51, 404-not-found, help-center

Not much to add to the title. Go to the **[Area 51 Discussion Area](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/)** and click the help link. You'll get the **[404 page for Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/help)**

Comment: Wow, nice catch! The [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) is still up.

Comment: The problem is that it redirects you from `http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/help` to `http://area51.stackexchange.com/help`. Area 51 doesn't have the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me!  Kidding aside, it's just a temporary (maybe) fix.  I've simply added a `/help` to `/faq` redirect on Area 51 itself.

I don't know what the long-term plan here is, obviously we overlooked that child meta relationship on the "go to parent" case.  We may not go to the parent in the discuss case, reverse my redirect, etc.  The boys on this project will figure it out Monday :)